# AngularJS - Why does $scope.property's value change when changing a variable referencing it

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I'm copying a `$scope.property` by defining it as the value of another variable `var query`, and when I update the value of `var query` it changes the value of `$scope.property`.

Why does this happen and how can I avoid this?

My code looks something like this:

```
var query = $scope.property;
if(condition) {
    console.log($scope.property);
    $.extend(query, anotherObj);
    console.log($scope.property);
}
```

The output in the console looks like this:

```
> Object {details-type: "order", details-bind_date_formatted: "03/19/2013"}
> Object {details-type: "order", details-bind_date_formatted: "03/19/2013", details-state: "CA"}
```

I've never encountered this problem in vanilla javascript.

Comment: Should I flag this question for having nothing to do with angular and having been answered before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does this happen

You noticed that `query === $scope.property`? The both refer to the exact same object, which you alter between the two log statements.

> and how can I avoid this?

How do you want to avoid this? Do you expect `query` to be a clone of the object? Then see [How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/728360/1048572) or [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/122102/1048572) for that.

> I've never encountered this problem in vanilla javascript.

Unlikely, since jQuery is only built of vanilla JS:

```
var scope = {a:{b:1}};
var a = scope.a;
console.log(scope.a); // or just log(a);
a.c = 0; // or scope.a.c = 0;
console.log(scope.a); // or just log(a);
```

Comment: I want to make a copy of the object rather than a reference to it.

Comment: I've been writing javascript for 2 years. I can't believe I've never noticed this until now. lol

Answer (score 2):

```
var query = angular.copy($scope.property);
```